# query about check constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraint

want to write a check constraint(while creating a table) which accepts value 
between 2 dates like ('25-oct-94' to '10-may-16')

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: i am using a simple database which having only date

Comment: Oh dear...which _vendor_ is your database, e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, etc.?

Comment: DBMS? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai MySQL doesn't support check constraints AFAIK.

Comment: i am using a sql

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen AFAIK it's even worst... it does not complain about them, but does not enforce them either. Making developers think they are OK since the create or alter statement have been completed successfully, but then just ignores the check constraint that might, of course, lead to corrupt data...

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Exactly. Little bit confusion.

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar sql is a language, not a product. people are asking you what is the product you are working with? Is it ms-access, oracle, MySql, Sql Server, PostgreSql, or something else I didn't mention?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes as Zohar said CHECk constraint is present in MySQL but Db engine won't enforce it at all and will ignore simply. So it's almost useless

Comment: i m using oracle

Comment: Why mysql does this ? What he wants from us ?

Comment: it gives error :- "date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint " 
create table dob5 
(
 birthdate date,
CONSTRAINT check_dates CHECK (birthdate BETWEEN '25-oct-94' AND '10-may-16') 
)

 this is how i tried –

Comment: Can you please post the create table statement.

Comment: @Rahul for what purpose, other then evolution by natural selection, are check constraints good for in MySql? I would say not only are they useless, they are even harmful in MySql...

Comment: want to write a check constraint(while creating a table) which accepts value before the year of 2000..
@AnkitBajpai

Comment: You can simply use the check constraint as `CHECK YEAR(date_col) <= 2000`

Comment: this line gives error ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
@AnkitBajpai

Comment: Now you have to post your whole Create table statement. Without that it is not possible for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `Oracle` you can use `CHECK` constraint saying

```
CONSTRAINT check_dates
  CHECK (my_date_column BETWEEN date '1994-10-25' AND date '2016-05-10')
```

Your query (as in comment) should be like below

```
 create table dob5 ( birthdate date not null, 
                    CONSTRAINT check_dates 
                    CHECK (birthdate BETWEEN date '1994-10-25' AND date '2016-05-10') );
```

See this demo fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/779f9

Comment: it gives error @Rahul :- "date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint " create table dob5 ( birthdate date, CONSTRAINT check_dates CHECK (birthdate BETWEEN '25-oct-94' AND '10-may-16') ) this is how i tried

Comment: ? are you there ?

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar, see edit in answer if helps

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar - you got that error because you did not create the constraint exactly as Rahul showed. You missed the `date` keyword, which is crucial when declaring date literals.

Answer (score 0):

please check this.

create table t

( your_columnnm date

check( your_columnnm between date '1994-10-25' and                                                   date '2016-05-10' ));

Comment: hey
can u tell me query for sql 
accept the date which is less than year 2000 using check constraint ?